# How to use the same function in different ways?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I have two dropdowns. When I select an option in the first dropdown, the second dropdown values will be changed according to the first dropdown values.

**HTML CODE**

```
<select id="one">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$("#one").change(function () {
    if ($("#one").val() == 'a') {
        $("#two").val("b")
    } else if ($("#one").val() == 'b') {
        $("#two").val("a")
    }
});

$("#two").change(function () {
    if ($("#two").val() == 'a') {
        $("#one").val("b")
    } else if ($("#two").val() == 'b') {
        $("#one").val("a")
    }
});
```

Both the code for two dropdowns do the same function. Is there any efficient way to reduce the code? Like declaring a common function and using it for both dropdowns (like a prototype)?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbophpo7/).

Comment: use of Native javascript will be better

Comment: If you wish to bind multiple DOM elements then I suggest using Knockout or AngularJS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add common `class` to the both drop-down.
2. Bind `change` event on the elements using common class
3. Use `siblings()` to set the `value` of other drop-down
4. Use `trigger()` to update the drop-down values on page load.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xygLekh8/)

```js
$('.mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var newVal = $(this).val() == 'a' ? 'b' : 'a';
  $(this).siblings('.mySelect').val(newVal);

  // Even Shorter
  // $(this).siblings('.mySelect').val($(this).val() == 'a' ? 'b' : 'a');
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one" class="mySelect">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select id="two" class="mySelect">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
$('#one,#two').on('change', function() {
  var other = ( $(this).attr('id') == 'one' ) ? '#two' : '#one';
  
  var value = ( $(this).val() == 'a' ) ? 'b' : 'a';
  
  $(other).val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many ways to do it:

```
function onChange($element, $other) {
  if($element.val() == 'a'){
    $other.val("b")
  }else if($other.val() == 'b'){
    $element.val("a")
  }
}
```

See it here:

```js
function onChange($element, $other) {
  if ($element.val() == 'a') {
    $other.val("b")
  } else if ($element.val() == 'b') {
    $other.val("a")
  }
}

$('#one, #two').change(function() {
  var other = $('#one, #two').not(this);
  onChange($(this), other);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function with two arguments to pass your dropdown ids:

```
$("#one").change(switchSelection("#two", "#one"));

$("#two").change(switchSelection("#one", "#two"));

function switchSelection(x, y) {
    if($(y).val() == 'a') {
        $(x).val("b")
    }
    else if ($(x).val() == 'b') {
        $(y).val("a");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (given your code) - though not *the* most efficient  - would be to pass the select elements in as parameters to a common function call.

```
var handleChange = function($select, $linkedSelect){
    if($select.val() == 'a'){
        $linkedSelect.val("b")
    }else if($select.val() == 'b'){
        $linkedSelect.val("a")
    }
}; 

$("#one").change(function(){
    handleChange($(this),$('#two'));
});

$("#two").change(function(){
    handleChange($(this),$('#one'));
});
```

[Here's a fiddle of that in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/hbophpo7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one,#two').change(function() {
 var opositeIdObj = {"one":"two","two":"one"};
 var opositeValObj = {"a":"b","b":"a"};
 $("#"+opositeIdObj[this.id]).val(opositeValObj[this.value]);
}).trigger('change');
```